# Free solver for MINP problems

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, solver, nonlinear-programming

I have a mixed-integer nonlinear programming (MINP) problem.
Is there a free solver for such a problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### [COUENNE](https://github.com/coin-or/Couenne)

An open-source deterministic global MINLP solver.

### [BONMIN](https://github.com/coin-or/Bonmin)

An open-source local MINLP solver.

**Update:** Octeract Engine is no longer free as of summer 2022. The free version has since been replaced by Octeract Neural.

### [Octeract Engine](https://octeract.com/octeract-engine/)

(our own solver) is a commercial massively parallel deterministic global MINLP solver that is [free for academics](https://octeract.com/get-a-licence/). What's more interesting is that **starting next month the 1-core version of Octeract Engine will also be free for commercial purposes (therefore for everyone)**. We're still setting up the web framework for people to get that version automatically, but in the meantime you can just request a [commercial trial](https://octeract.com/get-a-licence/) on our website and we'll send you the free 1-core licence automatically when the trial runs out.

Since I have written a lot of the code I cannot overstate how biased I am, but this is the solver I would recommend - as of the current version (1.9) the 1-core version **finds feasible solutions for 94.5% of 3,016 test problems** (pretty much every test problem ever published) within 30 minutes, which is vastly superior to open-source alternatives.