# On the global optimization solver Octeract

Tags: solver, global-optimization

A while back, I [read on this forum](https://or.stackexchange.com/q/5489) that Octeract is free for academic use and that for commercial use it is also free but users are restricted to 1 core. I cannot find anything on the [website](https://octeract.gg) to download or install this solver. Is this solver still available for free?

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for your interest. We discontinued the free version in 2022 due to various reasons, and the solver has been a paid product for all audiences ever since.

Our Neural service is free, but it's limited to 1MB/file for non-enterprise users due to compute costs. Note that, for the same reason, the free Neural model is our Neural Feasibility model. This means that it will instantly produce a feasible point, but does not do global (or local) optimisation.

Comment: Is "instantly" really the right word? It would be fantastic if there were a global feasibility solver which instantly produces a feasible point if there is one (and (preferably) instantly tells you if the problem is infeasible.).

Comment: @MarkL.Stone Well I'd say it's more accurate to say that we're working towards "instant". Compared to conventional technology it's now at the "very quickly" stage, but that's due to engineering limitations we have yet to resolve rather than theoretical limits. Right now it has an exceptionally high probability of producing a feasible point very quickly if there is one, but it can not provide any guarantees (so it e.g. can't prove infeasibility). It also breaks horribly once in a while, which is why it will be in beta for a while.